# JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException function DATE_ADD not found

Tags: mysql, hql, dateadd

I tried to use the MySQL function DATE_ADD in a nativeQuery

> UPDATE my_table SET my_date = DATE_ADD(my_date, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)

but I got the error:

> JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException function DATE_ADD not found

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the problem by simply using "+" which also works:

> UPDATE my_table SET my_date = my_date + INTERVAL 1 HOUR